# Disabling SHA-1 in TLS handshake in Linux

Tags: tls, linux, sha

As SHA-1 is not recommended, I want to disable the SHA-1 hash algorithm. I used OpenSSL API to set signature algorithm to SSL_CTX,

`static INT32 signAlgoList[24] = { NID_sha512, EVP_PKEY_RSA, NID_sha512, EVP_PKEY_DSA, NID_sha512, EVP_PKEY_EC,NID_sha384, EVP_PKEY_RSA, NID_sha512, EVP_PKEY_DSA, NID_sha384, EVP_PKEY_EC, NID_sha256, EVP_PKEY_RSA, NID_sha256, EVP_PKEY_DSA, NID_sha256, EVP_PKEY_EC, NID_sha224, EVP_PKEY_RSA, NID_sha224, EVP_PKEY_DSA, NID_sha224, EVP_PKEY_EC };`

Signature algorithm list:

```
(void)SSL_CTX_set1_client_sigalgs(sCtxMutualAuth, (int *)signAlgoList, 24);
(void)SSL_CTX_set1_sigalgs(sCtxMutualAuth, (int *)signAlgoList, 24);
```

After including these APIs in my program, SHA-1 is disabled in Windows (I am not seeing SHA-1 in Wireshark logs) but, still SHA-1 is not disabled in Linux (It is showing SHA-1 in Wireshark logs). Is there any other way to disable SHA-1 in Linux?

Comment: Note : My server is running in Linux and Client in Windows

Comment: Be more specific: which program(s) where are doing exactly what (client or server in TLS)? What protocol version(s)? (Sigalgs only works in 1.2 or 1.3, and only 1.1.1 implements 1.3.) Where/how exactly is SHA1 being used in the trace? (Sigalgs only controls signatures and certs, not HMAC and KDF, although KDF is not visible.)

Answer (score 3):

> As SHA1 is not recommended, ...

This initial assumption is wrong. The only place where SHA-1 is not recommended is where collision resistance is needed, i.e. signatures (for example signatures on certificates). SHA-1 is still fine to be used as a HMAC, it is still (together with the even older MD5) an essential part of the TLS 1.1 protocol etc.

Comment: Thats ok, I must disable SHA-1 in my program

Comment: Setting `sigalgs` as the Q does (or at least tries to) _does_ restrict signatures, both protocol-level (ServerKX and CertVerify) and certificate. only for TLS1.2+, but does NOT affect HMAC or KDF (although TLS1.2+ changes the KDF).